# Unable to Retrieve Data from Drop down Selected Item in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, aspxgridview

I want to retrieve data from drop down list which is present inside ASPxGridview I have `"FindControl"` to retrieve data but no change Why it's really confusing for me?

My drop downs are not hard coded binded. All drop down are bind with `web method` i believe due to this reason i am not able to retrieve data.

Is there any other approach to to achieve it same.

**ASPX**

```
  <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgDepots" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="grid"
        Width="100%"
        OnRowDeleting="dgDepots_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgDepots_RowInserting" OnRowUpdating="dgDepots_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="LocationCode" VisibleIndex="0">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
</Columns>
```

**.cs**

On insert Event

```
protected void dgDepots_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
        {

      e.Cancel = false;
      DropDownList list = (DropDownList)dgDepots.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl((GridViewDataColumn)dgDepots.Columns["LocationCode"], "ddlLocation") as DropDownList;
      //var Location = dgDepots.FindControl("ddlLocation") as DropDownList; // I tried this way but no change
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Insert_Line_Item", con);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationCode", list.SelectedIndex); 
      con.Open();
      int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close(); }
```

As i can see While debugging (Even Though after Selected field)

```
list.SelectedItem.Value is null
list.SelectedIndex is showing -1
```

After adding

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>

list.SelectedIndex is showing 0
```

I am using **content Place holder** in ASPX is may cause ? not sure about this

It means Its not selecting Drop downs value

I am to bind drop down list but while debugging on Server side (`Data Source`, `DataTextField`, `DataValueField` all fields are null)[Binding Drop down using webMethod] why ??

[Please click This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihbyt.jpg)

[Please click (binded all drop down list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqBf2.png)

[NullReferenceException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvsYN.png)

Comment: list.SelectedIndex returns zero when first item is selected, for no item selected it is -1.

Comment: @derloopkat I understand this things, but in my case after selection of field its showing -1 and after adding <asp:ListItem>  its showing 0 dont know why ?